# What is the recommended way to make a copy of a Cloud SQL Database in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

We would like to import our Cloud SQL database into BigQuery to query along with other datasets we have there.

What is the best path to doing this?

Comment: You need to write an event shipping arhitecture. There is a startup that does have a solution https://www.stitchdata.com/integrations/google-cloud-sql/google-bigquery/

Comment: @Pentium10 Thanks, this is definitely a good option we will consider. Was hoping for something similar within the Google Suite.

Comment: Let me know if you need some sort of help, I am not involved in the startup, but we integrate similar things.

Answer (score 1):

You can [export your data as CSV files](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#csv) and then [load them into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data#loading_csv_files).

Comment: I have tried this approach using `bq load` and always get parsing errors on import. e.g. "Error detected while parsing row
starting at position: 231897115. Error: Data between close double
quote (") and field separator.". I am looking to automate this, so either the API or CLI approach needs to work.

Comment: I wish I had a better suggestion. I know that the people on our team who work on the various data connectors are looking to bridge some of these gaps, but it doesn't address your problem in the short term. You may end up needing to export, sanitize, then import.

Comment: Thanks for the response @elliott. The sanitization requires significant time and resources for large exports, which is obviously not ideal. I believe exposing further escaping and encoding controls on the "gcloud beta sql instances export" functions may solve these issues. Where can I suggest this?

Comment: The [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B) is a good place to file suggestions for BigQuery if you don't see an existing issue. There should be a component in the issue tracker for Cloud SQL as well.

Answer (score 0):

Shamless plug for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624181/best-way-to-import-google-cloud-sql-data-into-bigquery#57947491) to a similar question: set up a "connection" to allow [Cloud SQL Federated Queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries) and do all the work directly within BigQuery:

```
INSERT
  demo.customers (column1)
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   EXTERNAL_QUERY("project.us.connection",
                  "SELECT column1 FROM mysql_table;");
```