# Move a database from cloud SQL Server to BigQuery in one go

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-sql

I have a database in cloud SQL Server. I need to move the database to BigQuery. Currently I'm using airflow to move one table at a time (downloading as `.csv` to gcs storage and then moving it to BQ).

Is there any other way to move all the tables in one go?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624181/best-way-to-import-google-cloud-sql-data-into-bigquery https://www.google.com/search?q=google+cloud+sql+to+bigquery+migration&rlz=1C5GCEM_enUS1061US1062&oq=google+cloud+sql+to+bigquery+migration&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.7967j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: The problem is federated queries works only for cloud SQL postgres or MySQL db, not for SQL server

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be enabling CDC and continuously replicating data from [SQL Server to BQ](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/sqlserver-to-bigquery).

> create and deploy a job that continuously replicates changed data from a Microsoft SQL Server database to a BigQuery table.

Or you can try @Nicholas Hansen-Feruch's recommendation of using [federated query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57947491/19378826).

Comment: Federated queries is not working for cloud SQL SQL server, but I'll try CDC ( I know nothing about it)

Comment: Also CDC won't work as I'm restoring the backup we receive as a new DB everytime (the data in cloud SQL SQL server is from backup file, delete the old db and restore the new data from the backup)